# How to match an optional substring in Lua Regex?

Tags: lua

I currently have this:

```
if not vim.fn.input('Confirm delete item ' .. idx .. '(y/n): '):match('[Yy](es)?') then return end
```

I want it to match `Y`, `y`, `Yes`, `yes`. But it seems that it didn't. So what's the correct way to match these four possibilities?

Comment: matching optional words is not possible with Lua's string patterns. you would need to combine multiple patterns. in a simple case like this you would explicitly check the 4 options using  the equality operator or a lookup table as shown below. I personally wouldn't accept anything but y or n if my prompt says (y/n)

Comment: @Piglet: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Yes = { ['Y']=true, ['y']=true, ['Yes']=true, ['yes']=true }
if not Yes[vim.fn.input('Confirm delete item ' .. idx .. '(y/n): ')] then return end
```

Comment: Great one! Thank you! (I somehow remember you on the math.stackchange btw)